# How to retrieve WhatsApp Graph api information with endpoints

Tags: api, whatsapp-cloud-api

I wanted to know how I can retrieve the contact list and the messages themselves through the endpoint with the whatsapp api, I can't understand how to get this information. And basic information like profile picture and other basic contact information.